# Path of least resistance for water?

Tags: water

If water follows the path of least resistance then why when slightly tipping a glass of water it runs down the side of the cup rather than dropping straight to the ground?

Answer (score 1):

Because there are other forces at work in this case besides just gravity- namely, surface tension. If you take that into account, then the water clinging to the side of the tipped glass as it runs down it *is*, in fact, following the path of least resistance.